# How to set as selected a new value from a select list with select2 and Twig templating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig, jquery-select2

I have been struggling with this to make it work.

I have a dropdown menu (by using the HTML select tag and the select2.js). In the database I have two values, these are retrieved and these are the values:

```
[{"type":"value1"},{"type":"value2"}]
```

And I display the data as follows with Twig:

```
<select multiple="" style="width: 100%" name="type" id="types" class="select2 req_place form-control input-sm">
                                        {% for type in types %}
                                        <option value="{{type.type}}" {% if request.post('type')==type.type %}selected{% endif %}{% if proyecto_o.type==type.type and request.post('type') is empty %}selected{% endif %}>{{type.type}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
```

This works fine. For example, if the form returns an error, due to another field whose validation failed, the previously selected option appears as selected.

However, if the user types a new value (which is allowed) as followed:

```
$("#types").select2({
    placeholder: "Seleccione...",
    allowClear: true,
    tags: true, /*This allows the user to type  a new value*/
    language: "es",
    maximumSelectionLength: 1,
});
```

the new value does not appear as selected. I have tried many ways to fix this, but I can't find out how to fix it.

For example, in one of my attempts, if i add the following code

Indeed, the new value still appears as selected, however, if i choose an already existing value from the database, it appears twice as selected!
I have tried by checking if the new value exists in the array, but still does not work.

```
<select multiple="" style="width: 100%" name="type" id="types" class="select2 req_place form-control input-sm">
                                        {% for type in types %}
                                        <option value="{{type.type}}" {% if request.post('type')==type.type %}selected{% endif %}{% if proyecto_o.type==type.type and request.post('type') is empty %}selected{% endif %}>{{type.type}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        {% if request.post('type') not in types %}
                                        <option value="{{request.post('type')}}" selected>{{request.post('type')}}</option>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </select>
```

Even though I am pretending to check if this new typed value does not exist in the array to put it as selected in the dropdown menu, it doesn't work yet, because if I choose a value that already exists in the database, it appears twice selected. If  I choose a new one, it appears once selected, which is fine.

Any ideas to fix this? How to make those already existing values in the database not to appear twice selected?

Comment: If you can, make this an answer instead of just posting it in your question. That way if others need to look at it, they can easily find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

I have found out how to make it work by using a flag.

```
<!-- Types-->
{% set type_flag = 0 %}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group {% if errors.has('type') %} has-error {% elseif request.post('type')%}has-success{% endif %}">
        <label for="types" class="control-label{% if proyecto_o.type %} text-primary{% endif %}">type</label>
        <select multiple="" style="width: 100%" name="type" id="types" class="select2 req_place form-control input-sm">
            {% for type in types %}
                <option value="{{type.type}}" {% if request.post('type')==type.type %}selected{% endif %}{% if proyecto_o.type==type.type and request.post('type') is empty %}selected{% endif %}>{{type.type}}</option>
                {% if request.post('type')==type.type %}{% set type_flag=1 %}{% endif %}
                {% if proyecto_o.type==type.type and request.post('type') is empty %}{% set type_flag=1 %}{% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if type_flag==0 and request.post('type') %}
                <option value="{{request.post('type')}}" selected>{{request.post('type')}}</option>
            % endif %}
        </select>
        {% if errors.has('type') %} <p class="help-block bg-danger">{{ errors.first('type') }}</p> {% endif %}
        <p class="help-block">Flag: {{ type_flag }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now both new and already registered values appear as selected.

If somebody else has a better way to do this, I will mark your answer as the accepted one plus upvoted. No problem.